# Starting Eclipse RCP from within Java code

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I would like to start a Eclipse RCP 3.x application from within Java code. I need to do this because I need to launch the RCP app from within a framework, that needs to be initialized first.

To have access to this other framework (which is SAP NetWeaver Mobile by the way), both applications need to run in the same JVM - therefore I can not call the .exe to start the RCP application. Within RCP I need to access the SAP framework.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks in advance and best regards, alex

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at what the .exe does:

[eclipse.c](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/index.cgi/org.eclipse.equinox.executable/library/eclipse.c?view=markup)

Basically, it starts the VM with this jar: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_xxx.jar and execute its org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main class

Answer (score 0):

Look at the EclipseStarter class.  I think you need to get the Equinox framework Jar file and have it be in your classpath to use this.  That's called org.eclipse.osgi.  If you have a situation where you are providing an API in your Java class to call into classes managed by Eclipses the situation gets considerably more complicated.  Make a comment on this if that's the case and I can provide some information there.